# Variable occurrence in a list of variables

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

Consider a (meta-logical) predicate `var_in_vars(Var, Vars)` which takes a variable `Var` and a list of variables `Vars` and succeeds if `Var` occurs in `Vars`. So we do not need to ensure that `Var` is a variable, nor that `Vars` is a list of variables.

What is the most compact and canonical way to express this in ISO Prolog? Here is an [overview of the built-ins](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) in ISO/IEC 13211-1:1995 including Cor.2:2012.

```
?- var_in_vars(V, [U,V,W]).
true.

?- var_in_vars(V, [X,Y,Z]).
false.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility:

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :- \+ unify_with_occurs_check(V, Vs).
```

and shorter:

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :- \+ subsumes_term(V, Vs).
```

**EDIT**: Future readers, please take into account the context of the question, which is a specific compactness challenge involving the expressivity of ISO predicates under given circumstances.

In other circumstances, you will likely benefit more from a definition like:

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :-
        must_be(list, Vs),
        once((member(X, Vs), V == X)).
```

Comment: Very nice, indeed! But there is one tiny little issue here (I admit it is out of scope of the standard): What if `V` is attached to some constraint, or just `freeze(V,eeek), var_in_vars(V, [A,B,C]).`

Comment: (For future readers): The second one is the accepted one. [`subsumes_term/2`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#subsumes_term) is a pure test predicate, with no unifications, wherease `unify_with_occurs_check/2` actually unifies the variable.

Answer (score 7):

this definition passes the tests, but... do I miss some subtlety ?

```
var_in_vars(V, [H|_]) :- V == H, !.
var_in_vars(V, [_|T]) :- var_in_vars(V, T).
```

Comment: It is certainly a good solution. Definitely not the most compact or canonical one.

Comment: Very nice first attempt! It takes courage to participate --> +1!

Comment: @mat: thanks! that was definitely the spirit I decided to post such naive answer. Since I read the clear hints in the questions (`we do not need to ensure that Var is a variable, nor that Vars is a list of variables`) that clearly indicate a list scan should not be required, I was lost browsing the docs... Your answer is very instructive indeed

Comment: @CapelliC: Your solution needs that assumption, too, for `var_in_vars(V.[V|nonlist])` succeeds

Answer (score 5):

And here goes another one, although a bit more complex:

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :-
   term_variables(Vs+V, Ws),
   Ws == Vs.
```

So this relies on the precise order how variables are visited. And since this is [well defined](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#term_variables) in the standard we can rely that they

> ... appear according to their first occurrence in left-to-right traversal ...

A drawback of this definition is that it has minimum cost proportional to the length of `Vs`.  But since an internal traversal is often quite efficiently implemented, this is not such a problem.

It has one big advantage: It only succeeds if `Vs` is a list of variables.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is:

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :-
    \+ (V = Vs, acyclic_term(Vs)).
```

But the solutions by @mat are better and more elegant and the solution by @CapelliC was for a long time the most portable one (the `subsumes_term/2` predicate was only standardized recently and not all systems provided the `unify_with_occurs_check/2` predicate).

Comment: `V = Vs` might be STO, and thus the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Yes, and one of the reasons I hesitated to post this solution for some time. Yet, so far, the only systems where I found this definition problematic is in systems that don't yet provide the `acyclic_term/1` standard predicate.

Answer (score 2):

The solution @false can be simplified to:

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :-
    term_variables(Vs+V, Vs).
```

When `V` is a member of the `Vs` list, the second argument returns `Vs` (due to the left-to-right traversal of the `Vs+V` term). When `V` is not a member of `Vs`, the second argument returns a list that have one more element than `Vs` and thus cannot unify with it. Although there's an implicit unification in the second argument, in neither case there's a danger of creating a cyclic term. I.e. unification being STO is not a problem in this simplified solution.

But is the simplification **worth** it w.r.t. performance? The use of equality, `(==)/2` have the potential of failing earlier and thus making the original solution faster.

Comment: This succeeds if the length of both lists are of the same length, however, it might produce unexpected unifications in case of, say `var_in_vars(V,[a])`

Comment: That's outside **your** stated conditions: "So we do not need to ensure that Var is a variable, nor that Vars is a list of variables.".

Comment: Right, but that a pure testing predicate actually unifies something is nevertheless something rather unexpected. You could put a `\+ \+` around, but then it **still** will unify, which might be observed via constraints.

Comment: In an ideal implementation of `term_variables(Vs+V,Ws)` the variable `Ws` might point directly to `Vs` should `V` occur in `Vs`. That is, at first the new `Ws` list is created, but upon success, it is realized that the "olde" `Vs` is good enough, the temporary `Ws` list might thus be immediately reclaimed.

Answer (score -1):

## Solution Synthesis

***Solution :*** Short

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :- \+ subsumes_term(V, Vs).
```

***Alternative 1 :*** Simple

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :- \+ unify_with_occurs_check(V, Vs).
```

***Alternative 2 :*** Depending on circumstances, this could be more suitable

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :-
        must_be(list, Vs),
        once((member(X, Vs), V == X)).
```

***Alternative 3 :*** More complex

```
var_in_vars(V, Vs) :-
   term_variables(Vs+V, Ws),
   Ws == Vs.
```

***Alternative 4 :*** Other possibility

```
var_in_vars(V, [H|_]) :- V == H, !.
var_in_vars(V, [_|T]) :- var_in_vars(V, T).
```

***Links :***

[Standard](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#term_variables)

---

**Note :** The context of the question, which is a specific compactness challenge involving the expressivity of ISO predicates under given circumstances.

Comment: **All** code of alternatives 1..4 comes from other answers. What's **your** contribution?

Comment: i am new to SO, and according to what "Joel Spolsky" said, it's good to make an answer that is full and clear even if the answer is taken from other users, the plus here is to make a full clear synthetic answer in one single place... i know it's debatable i agree. please let me know what you think and point me if i am wrong.

Comment: No offense, really. I was just surprised, when I was scanning through the answer and "connected the dots", to find out you digested the other answers. There is nothing wrong with that, but it's a first for me as a reader.

Comment: A compilation might be interesting if you are actually highlighting the differences. After all, there are minimal differences between all of them.