# Check occurrence in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate `occurs(Var, Term)` that succeeds if the Prolog variable `Var` occurs in the Prolog term `Term`, and fails otherwise.

```
% occurs(Var, Term)

?- occurs(X, f(X)).
true.

?- occurs(X, f(Y)).
false.

?- occurs(X, f(a,g(b,h(X,c),d))).
true.
```

I was thinking about such a thing but i want another solution if possible :

```
occurs(X,Y):- contains_term(X,Y).
```

Comment: Actually `contains_term/2` is not correct because it uses unification. You should use `contains_var/2`.

Comment: By *another solution* do you mean you are wanting to avoid the existing Prolog predicate `contains_var/2` that makes the problem easy? What's your requirement for *another solution*? If you want to do it "the long way" you would write a recursive rule using `(=..)/2`.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27389177/772868) for a similar problem

Answer (score 2):

A better name which clarifies a bit what you want would be

```
occurs_in(Var, Term)
```

Many approaches can use the same techniques as for [`var_in_vars/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27389177/772868).

This works in any ISO conforming system. It could be quite efficient, too ; that is, being (in the best case) independent of the size of `Term`.

```
occurs_in(Var, Term) :-
   \+ subsumes_term(Var, Term).
```

The next is good as long as you do not have any constraints:

```
occurs_in(Var, Term) :-
   \+ unify_with_occurs_check(Var, Term).
```

If you insist on using `contains_term/2` — (the name `term_subterm/2` would be much more appropriate):

```
occurs_in(Var, Term) :-
   once( ( contains_term(Term, Subterm), Var == Subterm ) ).
```

Or, to take into account Prolog superstitions:

```
occurs_in(Var, Term) :-
   \+ \+ ( contains_term(Term, Subterm), Var == Subterm ).
```

Answer (score 0):

I. Transform Term into a List with =.. Iterate over List

a. check if Head is Term with =..

b. Head == Var?

I uses elemSplit to check if Head has other Atoms stored

```
elemSplit(X,Out):- nonvar(X), X =.. Y, Y \== [X],
                              append(Y,[],Out), !, true.
elemSplit(_,_):- !, fail.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the problem:

```
member1(H, [H|_]):-!.

member1(X,[H|T]):-
    atomic(H),!,
    member1(X,T).

member1(X,[H|_]):-
    member1(X,H).

member1(X,[_|T]):-
    member1(X,T).

member1(x, [a,[b,[x,c],d]]).
```

I would use lists, instead of functions.
In this case the predicate returns true if the variable is member in the deep list and false otherwise.

I hope it will help you.