# Built-In predicate for checking for variable name in a list

Tags: prolog

Is there a built in predicate that can be used to check if a variable name is in a list. Similar to member/2 but will compare the variable names with '=='?

Comment: No there isn't. But writing such a predicate with `==/2` is just a few lines.

Comment: There are no variable names.  That is, they are discarded after reading in a term. For checking the occurrence of a variable in a list of variables see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27389177/772868).

Comment: Why do you want to check if a variable name is in a list? Maybe, you could make other way to get what you want.